# How to get all variables from a pipeline using the Azure REST API?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

I have a main ADO pipeline that has a list of variables and I have a second pipeline that will be triggered once the main pipeline is complete. Within this second pipeline, I am trying to make a call to the Azure Rest API to grab all variables from main pipeline, to then be used in subsequent jobs in the second pipeline.

My PowerShell script looks like:

```
steps:
- powershell: |
    $uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$(System.CollectionUri)/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/pipelines/1288/runs?api-version=6.1-preview.1"
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "$uri" -UseDefaultCredentials
```

This gives me an error saying: The resource cannot be found.

I think I'm just misunderstanding how using this API works. How am I able to retrieve all variables from a specific pipeline?

Comment: That was true in my code, edited the post to reflect. Actually error response is that it can't find the resource. I know the variables within the uri are correct as I'm using them in another pipeline. Could it be that I need a token or maybe headers?

Comment: If you're using `$(System.CollectionUri)` then you don't need to include the part of the uri string before that; it already has a value like `https://dev.azure.com/fabrikamfiber/`

Comment: If I remove `$(System.CollectionUri)`, I receive the same error saying it can't be found but I also just hardcoded the values and the pipeline passed but it's return the html from the ADO main page.

Answer (score 1):

In short: you need to authenticate your API call; you can use the built-in `$(System.AccessToken)` to do so.

There is a [predefined variable, System.AccessToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken), which carries the credentials of your service identity. You need to include this in the header of your API call, to authenticate.

```
$headers = @{ Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("user:$($System.AccessToken)")) };
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri -Headers $headers
```

Note: the API call may also require other flags to be set, for example a ContentType ; I recommend you read the docs on the [Azure DevOps REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1).